# Mac address not showing in ifconfig

Tags: kali-linux, ifconfig

My MAC address is not showing in kali linux using the `ifconfig` command. There is no option for *Hwr* inside *wlan0* which should contain the MAC address
how do I find my MAC address?

Comment: Might be that the driver for the NIC is not loaded (if `ifconfig` is displaying nothing about that NIC) or that the driver has loaded but is missing firmware for the NIC (if `ifconfig` shows very incomplete information). Without seeing the actual `ifconfig -a` output it is hard to tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ip addr` will do it, `ifconfig` is obsolete.

Comment: ifconfig -a should still work and show HWaddr.

Comment: @Adionditsak ip addr show the correct info if ifcfg-eth0 configured wrong info (i.e. mac).